# Sending Thousands of Request at the Same Time with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, threadpool

I need to develop an endpoint in rails that will send (possibly) hundreds/thousands of request, process it then return/render the json to user/client.

I've tried using thread pool with the size of 5, but it took forever, but when I tried increasing the size to the number of request, it threw `ThreadError: can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable` exception.

I don't think I can use background job/worker for this because I should return the result.

So what should I do?

I was thinking that I should wrap the process in 20sec timeout so it doesn't reach rails 30sec limit, and if it's still not finished in 20sec, it will return the unfinished result. It goes like this

```
result = Queue.new
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(20) do
        elements.each do |element|
          pool.process {
            response = send_request(element)
            result << response
          }
        end
        pool.shutdown
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      pool.shutdown
    end
    result = (Array.new(elements.size {result.pop})).flatten
    render json: {
        data: result
    }
```

But it's still not working, the process still keep going even after it timeout.

Comment: What data are you shipping to your users? You're sending 1000's of post requests?

Comment: @bkunzi01The problem is what I'm building is an api for an app but I don't have the data needed, so i need to send request to another api to get the data. So the flow is the app send a request to my api, and my api send request the other api to get the data, process the data, return the result as json

Comment: Ok so it sounds like you need to put a load balancer (like nginx) in front of your application and spin up multiple servers so the load balancer can allocate requests to avoid tying up one server. Then proceed as normal.